# TypeError: XM_ProgressBar is not a constructor when implemented in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, typescript

In HTML it's working well without any issues. But if implement in next js getting ***TypeError: XM_ProgressBar is not a constructor***.

[TypeError: XM_ProgressBar is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwzuF.png)

***xm_progressBar.min.js***

```
"use strict";

function _typeof(e) {
    return (
        // .... other methods
    )(e)
}

function XM_ProgressBar(h) {
    function e(e, t) {
        var n = t[0],
            i = t.substring(1);
        "." === n && e.setAttribute("class", i), "#" === n && e.setAttribute("id", i)
    }

    // .... other methods
}
```

***plugins.js***

```
const XM_ProgressBar = require('../xm_progressBar.min.js').XM_ProgressBar;
const XM_ProgressBar = require('../xm_progressBar.min.js');//

const existsInDOM = function (selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
};

const plugins = {

  createProgressBar: function (options) {
    if (existsInDOM(options.container)) {
      return new XM_ProgressBar(options);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = plugins;
```

***header.progressBar.js***

```
const plugins = require('../../plugins');

plugins.createProgressBar({
  container: '#logged-user-level',
  height: 4,
  lineColor: '#4a46c8'
});
```

I'm new to react and next js, please guide me to overcome this.